# Testing for Exception in Python with pyunit

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I need to test my python code for an exception but I can't seem to get the right statement to run.
When I test my production code I can see that the exception is thrown but when I test for this exception in my unit test file I get this:

```
testincorrectparam (unittestearnings.TestEarningsArgs)
should raise error when param not an integer ... "3v" is not a valid argument.  i should be an integer
ERROR
```

I read through similar questions on SO but I just don't manage to find a satisfactory answer for my problem..

The production code looks like this:

```
class Earnings():

    def printd(i=0):

        try:
            i = int(i)

        except Exception:
            print('"' + i + '"' + " is not a valid argument.  i should be an integer")
            sys.exit(0)
```

And the unit test code is this:

```
from earnings import Earnings
import unittest

class TestEarningsArgs(unittest.TestCase):

   def testincorrectparam(self):
      '''should raise error when param not an integer'''
      e = Earnings()
      value = "3v"
      self.assertRaises(Exception, e.printd(i=value))

if __name__ == "__main__":
      unittest.main()
```

Really appreciate any help.

Comment: Note that `printd()` doesn't take a "param" named parameter, so either your test or code is incorrect there as well.

Comment: @Wooble thank you for spotting this, the code is now consistent.  My question is still valid however.  Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that exception is catched, it's not propagated to unittest. You need to remove try-except statement and leave `i = int(i)`. In this case exception will be raised and `assertRaises` will catch it itself.

Another issue is line sys.exit(0) in your code. You need to either replace it with raise Exception(...) which isn't good as Exception class is not a specific exception (you should raise more specific exception for the situation you expect to error happen).

Comment: Rostyslav thank you your comment has helped me solve my question.  I am going to post a solution now.  Unfortunately I am not able to upvote your comment as I do not have the necessary seniority to do so.

Comment: Just accept the answer if it helped) Upvote is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

replace `sys.exit(0)` with `raise`

Comment: ... and you should be trying to catch ValueError rather an Exception in your try clause.

Comment: thank you.  I have decided to raise a custom exception instead based on the great examples I found in "Dive Into Python".  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

i am trying to learn unittesting in python i think the general form of assertRaise is

```
TestCase.assertRaises(Exception, callable, parameter1,parameter2,...)
```

so please try

```
self.assertRaises(Exception, e.printd,i=value)
```

hope it will work for you